# Resistors on SPI traces

Tags: pcb, spi

I was looking at the [schematic](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/eval-board-schematic/DC2365A2-SCH.PDF) for the [development](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/dc2365a-h.html) board for the [LTC2333-16](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc2333-16.html) ADC, and I was wondering what the purpose of the eleven 33 ohm resistors (R10-R20) on the SPI traces was.  There is no mention of these in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/233316f.pdf).  (See image below.)

I am designing a small breakout board to allow the ADC to communicate with a micro-controller, and I was wondering if I should include them.

cropped copy of dev board schematic:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly they are output series termination resistors used to (a) maintain a proper logic level at the far right of the bus and (b) dealing with transmission-line reflections that inevitably happen if the "recipient" to the far right is situated at such a distance to make the parallel bus into a transmission-line.

In other words, reflection control.

I also note that pin 36 of the ADC is named as ground in the data sheet yet you have named it SDO7 <-- is there are reason for this?

Comment: Thanks, Andy.  On the development board, they are connect to an FPGA.  But I've seen other boards with similar resistors on the SPI traces.  Do you think I should include them in my design?

Comment: I see no harm in adding them other than cost.

Comment: Regarding pin 36:  The attached image was a copy of the dev board schematic (see page one of link in my original post).  I did not catch that discrepancy.  In my schematic, I have pin 36 as a ground.

Comment: I’d be inclined to place the footprints and then see what value gives the best signal integrity

Comment: @Frog did you mean to leave this comment here or under the question aimed at the OP? At the moment I can't tell who you are addressing this to like, is your comment a criticism of my answer or something else? Clarity is needed. If it's aimed at the OP, I think it needs more than just seeing what value gives better signal integrity; for instance, you need to establish the impedance of the parallel bus going right and analyse the output impedance of the chip on the left then, you choose a resistor. I think you've been around enough t know how to use the `@person` thing.

Comment: @Frog.  Do you mean design the board, have it fabricated, and then experiment with resistor values?  If so, what parameter should I measure?  Also, since the board is all surface mount, I would like to get the design right the first time, as it will have a high initial cost.

Comment: Yes exactly, if you connect an oscilloscope you should be able to see any overshoot, ringing etc.  clk, cs and MOSI are all driven from the micro while miso is driven by the peripheral, also the latter may have different characteristics.  Or just place 0ohm resistors and have done with it.

Comment: @Frog.  Are the zero-ohm resistors place holders for to-be-determined value?  Or do they help with signal integrity?  Also the traces in my board are going to header pins.  The signal will leave the board and go to another board.  If I add these resistors to the path post-header pin, will this have the same effect?  It would be much easier to play around with resistor values on a separate board.

Comment: @Frog it's a poor initial comment you made that has just led to confusion and opened an unnecessary can of worms for the OP. It's your responsibility to dig your way out of this hole.

Comment: @njspeer if the signal paths are relatively long then impedance-matching will be more important than if the paths are short, especially if you plan to run the bus at high speed.  The datasheet will be based on a conventional arrangement with all parts on one PCB.  If you have the opportunity to do a first 'spin' of the board with many footprints and then a second where you remove any that you don't need then you could optimise the design, but if that isn't an option then you would want to trade off the potential risk of a noisy bus against the incremental cost of extra parts.

Comment: @Frog thanks.  The cost of the resistors is a non-issue.  If that is the safer way to go, then I will add them to the design.  It's a very low-volume project, but I am on a very short time frame and would like to get it right on the first design.